# How to plot Extreme-Value functions that have parameters with finite intervals?

Tags: plotting, intervals

I would like to calculate/plot $min$ and $max$ values of a function whose parameters have finite intervals but I am receiving error messages as follows:

```
h = 0.7; cspeed = 299792.458; Omega\[CapitalLambda]0 = 0.7; Omegam0 = 0.3; Omega0 = 1.0002; 
Yp = Interval[0.2534 + 0.0083 {-1, 1}]; alpha = Interval[0.17 + 0.03 {-1, 1}]; logvc0 = Interval[1.58 + 0.05 {-1, 1}]; logvc1 = Interval[3.14 + 0.38 {-1, 1}]; beta = Interval[-0.50 + 0.18 {-1, 1}];

func1[Yp_] := func1[Yp] = (1 - Yp)*0.0462/0.281;
func2[z_?NumericQ] := func2[z] = (0.281*(1 + z)^3)/(0.281*(1 + z)^3 + 0.719);
func3[z_?NumericQ] := func3[z] = func2[z] - 1;
func4[z_?NumericQ] := func4[z] = (18*\[Pi]^2 + 82*func3[z] - 39*(func3[z])^2)/func2[z];
func5[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := func5[z, p] = 96.6*((func4[z]*0.281*0.71^2)/24.4)^(1/6)*((1 + z)/3.3)^(1/2)*(10^(p - Log10[0.71] - 11))^(1/3);
func6[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, Yp_, alpha_, logvc0_, logvc1_, beta_] := func6[z, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta] = Log10[alpha] + Log10[func1[Yp]] + (beta + 1)*p + beta*(-11 + Log10[0.71]) - (Log[10])^-1*((10^logvc0/func5[z, p])^3 + (func5[z, p]/10^logvc1)^3);
```

Now would like to calculate $Min$ and $Max$ of the following function at values $z=0.03$ and $p=12$

```
func[z_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, Yp_, alpha_, logvc0_, logvc1_, beta_] := func[z, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta] = Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][func6][z, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta] // N;
```

using this line of code:

```
Min[func[0.03, 12, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]]
Max[func[0.03, 12, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]]
```

which doesn't give me any numerical answer.

> !(*SuperscriptBox[(func6), * TagBox[ RowBox[{"(",  RowBox[{"0",
>   ",", "1", ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", "0", ",", 
>        "0"}], ")"}], Derivative], MultilineFunction->None])[0.03, 12., Interval[{0.2451, 0.2617}],   Interval[{0.14, 0.2}], Interval[{1.53,
>   1.63}],   Interval[{2.76, 3.52}], Interval[{-0.68, -0.32}]]

The final goal is to plot them for any $p$ value as follows:

```
LogPlot[{Min[func[0.03, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]],
Max[func[0.03, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]]}, 
{M, 10.25, 12.95}, PlotRange -> {10^-3, 10^7.4}]
```

Comment: Thanks dear Feyre for the edit,

Comment: The result of `dNgalaxiesdzWSB[]` is an unevaluated Integral. In it, the function `LocalSMF` appears to not evaluate possibly due to the presence of the variable `p`.

Comment: I could not speculate about that one. Is there anyway to integrate M without introducing such complexity?

Comment: I think @Feyre is hinting that the argument corresponding to `M_?NumericQ` for `LocalSMF` appears to be a nonnumeric variable `p` in `dNgalaxiesdzWSB[]` -- that is, perhaps you miscoded your functions. (They're very complicated, which will be discouraging to many users, BTW.)

Comment: Just changed it to a MWE to be manageable.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the first part of your question.

It workes well, rationalizing the functions

(by the way, why do your use the double-definitions ":=" and "=" ? This makes only sense when exact the same parametervalues occur several times, That's not the case here)

```
    h = 0.7; cspeed = 299792.458; OmegaΛ0 = 0.7; Omegam0 = 
    0.3; Omega0 = 1.0002;
    Yp = Interval[0.2534 + 0.0083 {-1, 1}]; alpha = 
    Interval[0.17 + 0.03 {-1, 1}]; logvc0 = 
    Interval[1.58 + 0.05 {-1, 1}]; logvc1 = 
    Interval[3.14 + 0.38 {-1, 1}]; beta = Interval[-0.50 + 0.18 {-1, 1}];



    {func1[Yp_] = Rationalize[(1 - Yp)*0.0462/0.281, 0],
     func2[z_] =  Rationalize[(0.281*(1 + z)^3)/(0.281*(1 + z)^3 + 0.719), 0],
    func3[z_] = func2[z] - 1,
    func4[z_] = (18*π^2 + 82*func3[z] - 39*(func3[z])^2)/func2[z],
    func5[z_, p_] = 
                   Rationalize[
                   96.6*((func4[z]*0.281*0.71^2)/24.4)^(1/6)*((1 + z)/3.3)^(1/
                   2)*(10^(p - Log10[0.71] - 11))^(1/3), 0],
    func6[z_, p_, Yp_, alpha_, logvc0_, logvc1_, beta_] = 
          Rationalize[
                      Log10[alpha] + Log10[func1[Yp]] + (beta + 1)*p + 
          beta*(-11 + 
          Log10[0.71]) - (Log[
          10])^-1*((10^logvc0/func5[z, p])^3 + (func5[z, p]/
          10^logvc1)^3), 0]} // Simplify;

    func[z_, p_, Yp_, alpha_, logvc0_, logvc1_, beta_] = 
        Derivative[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0][func6][z, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, 
        logvc1, beta] // Simplify

    min1[p_] := Min[func[3/100, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]]

    max1[p_] := Max[func[3/100, p, Yp, alpha, logvc0, logvc1, beta]]

    {min1[12], max1[12]} // N

    (*   {0.316285, 0.704958}    *)

    Plot[{min1[p], max1[p]}, {p, 10.25, 12.95}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think `Rationalize` isn't actually necessary here?

Comment: That's true. Rationalize is not necessary. May be the problem was the definition with "SetDelayed" and usage of "?NumericQ".